# How to fix error in exporting Excel data to SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql

> Cannot insert the value null into
>   column
>   'COLUMN1',table'DB1.dbo.table1';Column
>   does not allow nulls. Insert fails.the
>   statement has been terminated.

This always shows if edit or save another data onto excel columns.

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into dbo.Table1 Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database="+ filepath + ";HDR=YES','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')", conn))
```

Is there a best way to handle this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try an SQL Statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT ISNULL(YourColumn, GETDATE()) FROM OPENROWSET(...)
```

GETDATE() is only one of many options. If your column does not support NULL values, you have to provide another value.

Greets
Flo

Comment: Not yet. I have 4 varchars columns and  3 date columns. on sheet 1.